# Impact of variance on the characterization of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Suppose I have two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$, and all I know is  that they take values from the same set of non-negative integers, their expectations are the same $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mu$, and their variances $\operatorname{Var}[X]=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^2]=\sigma^2_X$ and $\operatorname{Var}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mu)^2]= \sigma^2_Y$ are different.

Let's take $\sigma^2_X<\sigma^2_Y$.  It's clear that $Y$ is more "dispersed" than $X$, but can anything quantitative be said about the distribution of $X$ relative to $Y$ given $\mu$, $\sigma^2_X$, and $\sigma^2_Y$?  Say, for instance, something like $f[P(X\leq x),P(X\leq x)]\leq g(\sigma^2_X,\sigma^2_Y)$ where less-than-or-equals is used as an example (it could be some other relationship), $f[\cdot,\cdot]$ relates the distributions and $g(\cdot,\cdot)$ the variances.

Comment: What I am saying is trivial , but still I can only infer that the variable $X$ is truly random that is it takes different values

Comment: Hmmm...  you make an interesting point.  I'll re-phrase my question.

Comment: because if $var(X)=0$ you can infer that this random variable only takes one value . here it is $\ge c$ .

Comment: thanks for the comment.  I substantially changed the question.  not sure if there is an answer to this...

Answer (score 1):

The only comparisons this can yield must be based on integrals since each variance results from the compound effect of all the distribution. An example is as follows. For every random variable $Z$ with mean $\mu$ and every $z\gt0$, let 
$$\delta_Z(z)=P[|Z-\mu|\gt z].$$
The function $\delta_Z$ measures the decrease of the mass the distribution of $Z$ puts on the (symmetrical) deviations from the mean. Also, $\delta_Z(z)$ is the probability that, Bienaymé-Chebyshev inequality tells us, is bounded by $\sigma_Z^2/z^2$ for every $z$. Then, 
$$\sigma_X^2\lt\sigma_Y^2\iff
\int_0^\infty z\,\delta_X(z)\,\mathrm dz\lt\int_0^\infty z\,\delta_Y(z)\,\mathrm dz,
$$
for example because
$$
\sigma_Y^2-\sigma_X^2=2\int_0^\infty z\,(\delta_Y(z)-\delta_X(z))\,\mathrm dz.
$$